# Excel taking really long to calculate a UDF VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp77T.png)   [example1 The file name I'm trying to match is on Row A and I'm looking through Row I to see if there is a match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKyp1.jpg) I found this code I can't recall where but I am trying to match row of part numbers to a row of its image file names. This code works, however, there is a problem when I run it it takes really long to calculate even just 1 column and when I do hundreds at a time my excel just stops responding, and I have thousands of products I need to match. I am really new with VBA so I can't even figure out the problem.

Please help, thank you.

```
'Name function and arguments
Function SearchChars(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
'Declare variables and types
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
'Iterste through each cell
For Each cell In tbl_array
  'Save cell value to variable
  str = cell
  'Iterate through characters
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    'Same character?
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      'Add 1 to number in array
      a = a + 1
      'Remove evaluated character from cell and contine with remaning characters
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  'Next character
  Next i
 
a = a - Len(cell)
'Save value if there are more matching characters than before  
If a > b Then
  b = a
  Value = str
End If
 
a = 0
Next cell
'Return value with the most matching characters
SearchChars = Value
End Function
```

Comment: `For Each cell In tbl_array` - this is iterating cell-by-cell, which is very slow. Instead you want to read `tbl_array.Value` into a `Variant` array, and then loop the array. In other words, you think you have an array, but you actually don't.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. So do I change For Each cell In tbl_array to For Each cell In tbl_array.Value? Sorry, I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Perhaps read [Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) first.

Comment: Try switching Excel from Automatic Calculation to Manual: File->Options->Formulas . It's possible that Excel is recalculating the whole workbook after every cell is updated.  If you set it to Manual, you can just hit F9 to manually recalculate once the script is done running.  That might not fix it entirely but it could make a big difference

Comment: @ANeonTetra I tried this and it was calculating faster, however, for some reason it's not as accurate?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the searching method. The code is changing the value it is searching within, while searching. Using `Instr(cell, ` and then changing the `cell` value is recursive and costly. Whenever you change a cell value, the application wants to re-calculate and run `Worksheet_Change` events, and do a Screen Update if that cell is visible. @BigBen 's advice of taking everything into an array is much better, for many reasons.

Comment: @jigz without seeing the spreadsheet it's hard to say, but if the script is reading data from cells with formulas , and relying on the values of those formulas being accurate during runtime, then yeah it's possible it won't calculate the correct results.  It sounds like a significant rewrite like other responders are saying would be the best bet

Comment: @ANeonTetra thank you for your help!

Comment: As others have said, without seeing a sample of the data and what you're trying to do, it's hard to help. On how to do that: edit your question and uses `?` (help). You can make a table or post an image (e.g. screen snapshot). Suggest just a few data rows will do. Also, your OP title suggests this is a `UDF`. `User Define Functions` means a function you use in Spreadsheet cell (i.e. as an `Excel` `Formula`), but I'm pretty sure your code won't work that way.

Comment: Hi @Spinner, I am using it as an Excel Formula. And I'm gonna post a sample of my sheet. I'm just waiting for my excel to stop calculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT (post seeing the data)**: The following should be notably faster (as well as notably simpler)

```
'Name function and arguments
Function SearchChars(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
    
    'Declare variables and types
    Dim inLenMatched%, vnVal, varLookupValues()
    
    'Puts lookup cell values into a array (to speed things up)
    varLookupValues = tbl_array.Value
    
    'Iterate through each lookup value
    For Each vnVal In varLookupValues
      
        'Ignore empty cells
        If vnVal <> "" Then
            
            'Does part number appear in filename?
            If InStr(lookup_value, vnVal) > 0 Then
                
                'Is this match the most complete match so far?
                If Len(vnVal) > inLenMatched Then
                    inLenMatched = Len(vnVal)
                    SearchChars = vnVal
                End If
             End If
        End If
        
    Next vnVal
    
    'Return match value (or 'No Match' if not matched)
    If SearchChars = "" Then SearchChars = "No Match"

End Function
```

The above is just one off-the-cuff approach.
There are other (and quite possible faster) ways to approach this.

The most obvious step (regardless of method) to improving performance would be to limit `tbl_array` to only the rows with data (not the entire column).

Separately: Without knowing all possible cases, it's impossible to say for sure. But, in all probability, this can be done with Native excel functions, and (if so) that will deliver the best performance.

Comment: Thank you @spinner, I will give your code a try. I posted a screenshot of a sample of my data  on my post.

Comment: This works really great, however, it still partially matches a lot instead of just filling the column with "No match".

Comment: 1) Glad to help. 2) Not sure I understand. Can you give a example of what you mean? 3) Separately: Are all the filenames in the form `??_PartNumber_??.jpg`?

Comment: I put a screenshot on my post named "example2".

Comment: so on the "all_filenames" are its .jpg and one part number could have multiple images. but some part numbers may not even have .jpg available. I've tried the VLOOKUP formula already, but the problem with that is because one part number can have 2 or 3 images and has an extra letter or words at the end, it won't match it.

Comment: Confused here re `Example 2`: My latest code above will not produce that outcome. My previous code (Pre **EDIT**) would (as would your original code). Are the highlighted rows in `Example 2` what you'd want as a valid match, or what you don’t want as a match?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess my previous code was still on those line and going through the sheet I found your code to be working just fine and putting "No match" next to it. Again, thank you so much for your help!!!! :)))

Comment: Easy mistake to to make. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

As said, minimizing the interactions with the sheet by assigning the range to an array will structurally make your macros faster.
Not tested but these minor changes in your code should help you on the right track:

```
    Option Explicit
    'Name function and arguments
    Function SearchChars2(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
    'Declare variables and types
    Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
    'Iterste through each cell => replace with array
    'adapt to correct sheet
    Dim arr
    arr = tbl_array
    
    For Each cell In arr 'tbl_array
        'Save cell value to variable
        str = cell
        'Iterate through characters
        For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
          'Same character?
          If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
            'Add 1 to number in array
            a = a + 1
            'Remove evaluated character from cell and contine with remaning characters
            cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
          End If
        'Next character
        Next i
     
        a = a - Len(cell)
        'Save value if there are more matching characters than before
        If a > b Then
          b = a
          Value = str
        End If
         
        a = 0
        Next cell
    'Return value with the most matching characters
    SearchChars2 = Value
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi @ceci, I copied and pasted your code in my VBA. I'm currently trying it and It's been processing for quite some time.

Comment: I still don't like the `Instr(cell,...` -> `cell = ` loop. It seems like one of the least efficient ways of counting matching characters.

Comment: Hi @ceci, it's a little faster if I do it by increments.

Comment: ok just changed the array part, could you give an example of some source data?

Comment: New here too, should I just put one of the excel files here?

Comment: just a sample of your data.

Comment: @ceci, I have uploaded a picture example of my data.

Comment: ok so the fastest way to do this is not a UDF but getting all values into an array and dictionary, doing the match and writing back to the sheet. Just wondering, can you test performance with this native search function: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I1;A1));I1;"no match")

Comment: @ceci I tried this formula but it just give me an error.

Comment: I'm on an EU version of Excel, you just need to replace semicol by comma: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I1,A1)),I1,"no match")

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to modify your existing code, but I found it easier to just rewrite it using what I consider to be a better structure. And After running the code over 26 columns & 432 rows, It only took 0.2 seconds to find the Closest Matching String.

I moved every value into an array.
I converted the `lookup_value` and the "cell values" into an array of bytes.
I compared the byte arrays to count matching "characters".
And then I return the string that had the highest number of matching "characters".

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim StartTime As Double
    StartTime = Timer * 1000
    Debug.Print SearchChars3("Toddleson", Range("A1:Z432"))
    Debug.Print "Time Elapsed: " & Timer * 1000 - StartTime & " ms"
    'Time Elapsed: 171.875 ms
End Sub

Function SearchChars3(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
    Dim ClosestMatch As String, HighestMatchCount As Integer
    
    Dim tbl_values() As Variant
    tbl_values = tbl_array.Value
    
    Dim LkUpVal_Bytes() As Byte
    LkUpVal_Bytes = ToBytes(lookup_value)
    
    Dim Val As Variant
    For Each Val In tbl_values
        If Val = "" Then GoTo nextVal
        
        Dim Val_Bytes() As Byte
        Val_Bytes = ToBytes(CStr(Val))
        
        Dim MatchCount As Integer
        MatchCount = CountMatchingElements(LkUpVal_Bytes, Val_Bytes)
        
        If MatchCount > HighestMatchCount Then
            HighestMatchCount = MatchCount
            ClosestMatch = Val
        End If
nextVal:
    Next
    SearchChars3 = ClosestMatch
End Function

Function ToBytes(InputStr As String) As Byte()
    Dim ByteArr() As Byte
    ReDim ByteArr(Len(InputStr) - 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To Len(InputStr) - 1
        ByteArr(i) = AscW(Mid(InputStr, i + 1, 1))
    Next
    ToBytes = ByteArr
End Function

Function CountMatchingElements(Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant) As Integer
    'As elements from Arr1 are found in Arr2, those elements are removed from Arr2, to prevent re-matching with the same elements
    'To enable this feature, Arr2 is turned into a Collection
    Dim Col2 As New Collection
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In Arr2
        Col2.Add v
    Next
    
    Dim MatchCount As Integer, i As Long
    For Each v In Arr1
        For i = 1 To Col2.Count
            If Col2.Item(i) = v Then
                MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                Col2.Remove (i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    CountMatchingElements = MatchCount
End Function
```

A further optimization could be to have a second version of the `ToBytes` function that directly outputs the values into a `Collection`. Then, you can change `CountMatchingElements` to accept a collection and it wont need to convert the second array into a collection.

I will leave that as an idea for you to experiment with.

Comment: Thank you so much @Toddleson, I will be trying your code out!